# Search for XIB in main Bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xib

I'm developing a library and i have a xib file for `UITableView` cell.
I want to first search in main Bundle for user `XIB` file and if there is not that file then use my own `XIB`.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First search a `NIB` in `+[NSBundle mainBundle]`, then, if there's no one, search in `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]`, as argument give some class from your library.

Search a `NIB` with `-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check in your code

```
if([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your XIB name" ofType:@"nib"] != nil) 
{
    //file found
}
```

Comment: This works better if you want to determine if a nib file exists and not just attempt to load a nib directly!